# AWS S3 CP Cost Optimization

Tags: amazon-s3

Regarding cost optimizations what would be the cheapest

```
aws s3 cp local-data  s3://same-backet/latest
aws s3 cp local-data  s3://same-backet/some-date
```

or

```
aws s3 cp local-data  s3://same-backet/latest
aws s3 cp s3://same-backet/latest  s3://same-backet/some-date
```

I.e. does bucket-to-bucket copy would use less external (to AWS) traffic then local-to-bucket or it would it make even bucket-local-bucket trip to complete the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are few insights using which you can determine the cost that would be incurred for S3 use.

1. Data transferred between `S3 buckets` in the same `AWS Region` does not incur any cost
2. Any kind of data transfer IN S3 does not have any cost
3. Data transfer OUT to internet is free upto 1GB/Month

So if you transfer data from your local machine to S3, that will be IN, so not cost, safe to use the below transfers

```
aws s3 cp local-data  s3://same-backet/latest
aws s3 cp local-data  s3://same-backet/some-date
```

Your second option is also safe as you are transferring data in the same bucket, can also transfer data to another bucket in the same region without having to spend extra.

Suggesting to review the [AWS S3 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) page.

Answer (score 2):

All the answers by @subhashis-pandey are correct but S3 also costs for `GET` and `PUT` objects, inspite of object(s) being big or small, if your data can be ziped to single file, you need to keep ziped version of data where ever possible.